# Can you have more than two accounts on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

Can I have more than two Instagram accounts? And if yes, how can I add another one?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same email address for both?

Answer (score 7):

Instagram doesn't place any limit on the number of accounts you can create, as long as you provide a different email address for each one. The Instagram mobile application supports signing in with only one account at a time, although third-party programs enable you to manage multiple accounts from a single interface.

Comment: Actually, I can no longer create an account from my device (or IP?). I'm guessing there's a limit to how many accounts you can create in one device/IP.